# Difficulty in understanding the backtracking logic

Tags: java, algorithm, backtracking

I was trying to write the code for all possible subsets for an array of unique elements.

e.g. Input : nums=[1,2,3]
Output: [[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]
The output can be in any order.

I see this particular code is working correctly and satisfying all test cases.

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
        List<List<Integer>>solution= new ArrayList<>();
        backtrack(solution,new ArrayList<>(), nums,0);
        return solution;
    }

    private void backtrack(List<List<Integer>> sol, List<Integer>tempList, int[] nums, int start){
        sol.add(new ArrayList<>(tempList));
        for(int i=start;i<nums.length;i++){
            if(!tempList.contains(nums[i])){
                tempList.add(nums[i]);
                backtrack(sol,tempList,nums,i);   
                tempList.remove(tempList.size()-1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I get following output which is correct `[[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,3],[2],[2,3],[3]]`

However I am having a doubt  that when templist=[1,2,3] the if clause should prevent the further function call enclosed within it. However I see that                 `tempList.remove(tempList.size()-1);` is still being called and **2** and **3** are being removed after that.
Can anyone please clarify how this is being possible as the *if condition* should have prevented the removal of the last elements of the tempList. ?

Comment: Try to debug your recursive method.

Comment: @nonas What is there to debug? OP said that the solution works, they just want an explanation as to why it works.

Comment: Morgan, OP asked why the `if condition [...] prevented the removal` so first he/she should try to test/debug his/her recursive method. Or draw a tree diagram as you did.

Comment: Debugging is not limited to "search bugs". While debugging, you can follow the loop execution step by step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. The if-statement will not pass when `tempList = {1, 2, 3}`. This makes sense as the condition is: `!tempList.contains(nums[i])`, since in this scenario `tempList` and `num` are identical in elements, the if-statement will not pass.

So why does it look like the if-statement passes when `tempList = {1, 2, 3}`? We can see that after [1, 2, 3] there are seemingly unreachable states, namely: `[1, 3], [1], [2, 3], [3]`. This is in fact an illusion as these states were caused by the function being called by earlier cases.

This is because the recursive function branches variably. As in, some "nodes" will branch into several other nodes, while others will simply terminate. Consider the following diagram with num = [1, 2, 3] and the starting node being the empty array:[image: Tree]

There are two primary ways to traverse this tree.

1. [Breadth-first Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)
2. [Depth-first Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

I believe you expected your solution to traverse it in a breadth-first search manner, which would output the following:

`[[], [1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`

In reality, your solution traverses the tree in a depth-first search manner which explains your output of:

`[[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3], [2], [2, 3], [3]]`

This is because it follows the tree in this order:
[image: Depth-first Search traverse of tree]

Comment: BTW, thanks for doing the explanation of this homerwork. Link to Leetcode (Permutation in Java): https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/. Here link to solution code (same as OP): https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations/solutions/18239/A-general-approach-to-backtracking-questions-in-Java-(Subsets-Permutations-Combination-Sum-Palindrome-Partioning)/comments/188227/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes the scenario more clear now.

Comment: @Kumar_Maddy In that case, do you mind marking the answer as correct?